# After restarting mysql(Mariadb) it takes 5 minutes to restart

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am running Mysql(mariadb 5.5.64 version) on CentOS 7.
When I reboot OS or restart mysql, it takes 5 minutes to restart.
I have seen the log.

```
200421 16:10:01  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
200421 16:11:02  InnoDB: Waiting for worker threads to be suspended
200421 16:12:02  InnoDB: Waiting for worker threads to be suspended
200421 16:13:02  InnoDB: Waiting for worker threads to be suspended
200421 16:14:02  InnoDB: Waiting for worker threads to be suspended
```

Mariabdb is waiting for a worker thread to be killed.
but it is never killed eventually MySQL reach timeout(5 minutes) and further processing is going on.
It is now painful for me to wait more than 5 minutes for rebooting OS.
I've changed some MySQL variables. it does not work perfectly.
Is there any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What variables did you change?  Before doing the shutdown, what did `SHOW PROCESSLIST` say?

Comment: As I remember,  the variables are related to INNO DB, not clear remember but they were variables end with dirty page something.